# Best way to create a gradient loading indicator line in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am looking to create an effect of a gradient loading indicator. Something along these lines:

https://jsfiddle.net/k6cvun1z/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

but for React Native.

I haven't found a library that does it so I am looking to build it from scratch. I have tried using:

- ScrollView
- Animated.View with left
- Animated.View with transform

Each one had its problems:lag, going back to the start of the animation.

Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Have you tried to track down the reason for lag? It may be as simple as optimizing the app a little. Gradients are a bit tricky in react native. May be a combination of [`react-native-linear-gradient`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) and [`react-native-progress`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress) could work? I haven't tried it, just throwing ideas out there!

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle to demonstrate my goal. The react-native-progress doesn't have gradient line afaik. react-native-linear-gradient requires linking and I'd rather avoid linking if I can use a pre-made image. If there was a library that supports animated gradient perhaps I'd link it.